# Can I generate cucumber html report without command line(node cucumber-html-report.js) in cypress?

Tags: cypress

Can I generate cucumber html report without command line in cypress. Instead executing in terminals

Answer (score 0):

In package json file inside script add this below code
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test:open": "cypress open",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"start-server": "nodemon server.js",
"clean:reports": "if exist cypress\cucumber-json rmdir /S/Q cypress\cucumber-json",
"pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
"scripts": "npx cypress-tags run --env "TAGS=@SmokeTest" --headed --browser chrome",
"posttest": "node cucumber-html-report.js",
"test": "npm run scripts || npm run posttest",
},

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).